# Calling __init__ of all parent class with different parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have some class structure like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A")
class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__() # ???

c=C()
```

As you can see, `A` and `B` both are parent class of `C`. I want to call both classes `__init__` in `C`'s `__init__`. I want to pass some parameter to B's `__init__`. Is there any way I can do this with `super` keyword? I think that this will work:

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__()
        B.__init__(5)
```

Should we call `__init__` directly in such a way, or is there any better solution for this?

Comment: The prerequisite for cooperative super calls is that all the inherited methods have compatible signature throughout the whole hierarchy. If you're interested only in implementation reuse, composition/delegation may be a better design choice than multiple inheritance (depending on the context etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide self as parameter to parent classes' __init__().

```
class C(A,B):
def __init__(self):
    A.__init__(self)
    B.__init__(self, 5)
```